# jQuery - separate styles for grid/list view

Tags: jquery

For each instance of `.content` there are grid & list buttons set up to toggle functions for `styleList()` and `styleGrid()` on load, and on click.

The issue with my code is that the grid/list toggle is applying to all `.items` and not just the ones associated with the buttons.

How do I change the code so that the `styleList()` and `styleGrid()` functions apply only each instance of `.content` and don't iterate over every `.item`?

**NOTE:** I also need the solution to work with `appendTo` and `prependTo` in addition to modifying the CSS I will need to move elements within each `.item` depending on the view.

```js
function styleList() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("img").css("border", "");
    $this.find("img").prependTo($(this).find(".test"));
  });
}

function styleGrid() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("img").css("border", "4px solid green");
    $this.find("img").appendTo($(this).find(".test"));
  });
}
$(".content").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.find(".list").attr("data-view") == "list") {
    styleList();
  }
  if ($this.find(".list").attr("data-view") == "grid") {
    styleGrid();
  }
});
$(".toggle--list").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest(".content");
  $this.find(".toggle").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".toggle--list").addClass("active");
  styleList();
});

$(".toggle--grid").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest(".content");
  $this.find(".toggle").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".toggle--grid").addClass("active");
  styleGrid();
});
```

```css
.test {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  padding: 1.3rem
}

.view {
  display: flex;
}

.view>div {
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="toggle toggle--grid">
      <div class="icon icon--grid">grid</div>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle toggle--list active">
      <div class="icon icon--list">list</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list" data-view="list">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="toggle toggle--grid active">
      <div class="icon icon--grid">grid</div>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle toggle--list">
      <div class="icon icon--list">list</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list" data-view="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150" />
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `styleList` and `styleGrid` functions to only modify the closest element then you could pass `$this` as a parameter, e.g:

```js
$(".toggle--list").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this).closest(".content");
  $this.find(".toggle").removeClass("active");
  $this.find(".toggle--list").addClass("active");

  styleList($this); // passing $this (".content" element) to style function
});

function styleList(content) {
  // don't need to use .each() as .css() will apply to all elements matching the selector
  content.find(".item img").css("border", "");
}
```

I'm sure you may have reasons for creating functions to style sections of your HTML, but generally it's a lot cleaner to leave styling to CSS and using JavaScript to toggle classes/attributes instead. Here's a simplified version which achieves the same thing (I think):

```js
$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
  var $this    = $(this);
  var $content = $this.parents(".content");
  var style    = $this.attr("data-toggle-style"); // "list" or "grid"

  // Handle .active class
  $content.find(".toggle.active").removeClass("active");
  $this.addClass("active");

  // Set [data-style] attr to inherit CSS styles
  $content.find(".list").attr("data-style", style);
})
```

```css
.view {
  display: flex;
}

.view>div {
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.active {
  background: blue;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Add styles here instead of JS */
.list[data-style="grid"] img {
    border: 4px solid green;
}
.list[data-style="list"] img {
    /* something else */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="toggle" data-toggle-style="grid">
      <div class="icon icon--grid">grid</div>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle active" data-toggle-style="list">
      <div class="icon icon--list">list</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="toggle active" data-toggle-style="grid">
      <div class="icon icon--grid">grid</div>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle" data-toggle-style="list">
      <div class="icon icon--list">list</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That example may not be exactly what you're looking for but hopefully it gives you an idea of how you can simplify things if you wish to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if instead of just modifying the `css` I wanted to use `appendTo` where if for example in `styleList()` I move a div to one position inside of the `.item` while in `styleGrid()` the same div is to be moved to another location inside of the `.item`?

Comment: That sounds simple enough - `.appendTo()` detaches/moves elements so your `styleList` / `styleGrid` functions could easily be adapted to do that.

Comment: I tried to add `.appendTo()` to your code but I am having trouble configuring it inside of the function. It seems every time I call the `styleGrid()` it duplicates the items: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/BaLoOwj

Comment: Ah, my bad - I just read the docs more closely for `appendTo` and it states "If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except the last, and that new set (the original element plus clones) is returned."

Try looking up `.detach()` instead.

Comment: I looked up `.detach()` but am not sure how to incorporate it with your code. Would you be willing to update your snippet with a working solution?

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/v7rm5y1j/